# Reduce amount of files (or dependencies) in node_module folder

Tags: node.js, package, node-modules

We are running multiple node.js micro services.
A part of our deployment process has an "unzip task" and it takes over 10minutes because of the amount of files in the node module folder.
We cant run npm install on the servers on which those micro services are running on because of security issues.

I was wondering if there are any common ways to reduce the amount of files and maybe the dependencies in the node module folder?
Because even when I reduce the size of the folder by tens of mega bytes the amount of files still remains very big.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to bundle the entire project into a single file and/or executable.
To bundle your project, you use [ncc](https://github.com/vercel/ncc) and execute it like this:

```
ncc build input.js -o dist
```

This will create the index.js in the dirst folder, with all other files bundled together. It's also possible to require native node files.
It might be an issue if you have dynamic requires in your code base.

To create a single binary, you can use [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg). It supports different node versions and builds cross-platform:

```
pkg index.js
```

Create files "index-linux", "index-macos" and "index-win.exe".

Of course, you can combine both packages nicely.
This should reduce the amount of files you want to deploy.
Of course, this makes debugging through it rather difficult. So keep that in mind when going that route!

Comment: Looks interesting, but I didnt find any info about what the input.js file needs to include in it? Any chance you can expand on that?
On a side note, I will need to check if that can work, because at the moment we are running those services on IIS (with the help of "iis-node")

Comment: The `index.js` file is just the entry point to your application with many requires in it. Onbiously, it can have a different name as well so don't worry about that.
The result of that is either a bundled file or the executable with nodejs. All other `node_modules` are bundled in either case so that you end up with one file.